# Writing results to binary file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, binaryfiles, fwrite

I'm attempting to write the results of my code into a binary code.

I have a student's version of MATLAB so I'm not sure how to run the through the debugging process.

In any case, I'm not sure if this loop process will work with the fwrite function or not.

```
function write_out(A, file_name)
fid = fopen(file_name, 'w+');
if fid < 0
    error('error opening file %s\n', file_name);
end
[nrow ncol] = size(A);
total = 0;
for i = 1:nrow
    for j = 1:ncol
        if A(i,j) ~= 0
            total = total + 1;
        end
    end
end
d = total;
w = [];
k = [];
for i = 1:nrow
    for j = 1:ncol
        if A(i,j) ~= 0
            w = [w;A(i,j)];
            k = [k;[i,j]];
        end
    end
end
fwrite(fid, nrow, 'uint32');
fwrite(fid, ncol, 'uint32');
fwrite(fid, total, 'uint32');

for i = 1:nrow
    for j = 1:ncol
        fwrite(fid, w(i), 'uint32');
        fwrite(fid, w(j), 'uint32');
        fwrite(fid, k(i,j), 'double');
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Did you run the code? Did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with that size of `w` and `k`. From what I see, the size of `w` is `total x 1` and the size of `k` is `total x 2`. Yet you access them in a 2d loop with the dimensions of `a`...

BTW, you should learn how to use MATLAB's vector and matrix operations instead of loops. For example, you can calculate `total` without a loop:

```
total = sum(sum(A~=0));
```

and also `w` and `k`:

```
w = A(A~=0);
k = ind2sub(find(A~=0));
```

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to write, but you can use

```
fwrite(fid,w,'uint32')
```

to write the entire vector at once.

Comment: I'm trying to write the row position of each non-zero element in A (where I wrote w(i)), the column position of each non-zero element in A (where I wrote w(j)), and the actual element that is non-zero in A (where I wrote k(i,j), which I now realized was a mistake).

Comment: But I see that k holds the indexes and w holds the values